# Why I cannot see new iOS builds in Testflight

Tags: ios, testflight

I am new to TestFlight. I signed up for TestFlight and installed TestFlight on my iPhone device.

I got message "There are no available builds.You will receive an install email when a build is available." when i tried to open TestFlight in safari.

I also got confused regarding, whether i have to wait still i receive install email or any wrong in my procedure. Also i am not getting how to upload a build to TestFlight. Can anyone suggest me the best solution/links for this?

Answer (score 2):

as Nirav Bhatt said you need to upload build on your test flight account  for that you need to create .ipa file from xcode. 
refer this link of testflight to create ipa http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/494413-how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4-3-

once you crate ipa than you logged in you account there you need to drag drop you .ipa  this start uploading process.

once it finish it ask you to select person that can able to download this build with check box check the person whom you want to give rights than select option to notify with mail. that would notify selected users.

once process done open test flight application in your device you may see your build than click on it and download it.

for upload refer this link http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/890477-how-do-i-upload-a-build-

for more about quires you can check this link http://help.testflightapp.com/

hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should upload a build first. Once done, you should notify concerned people (including yourself - by selecting either your device UDID or email id) in your testflight account team. Once both are done, you will start seeing builds.

**UPDATE:**

Once you register, inside your dashboard you should see Upload build button.
Click it, and it will prompt for dropping your .ipa file.
Select and drop, and press green Upload button to actually upload.

Once uploaded, it will present a button called "Update profile". 
You must click it if you are uploading for the first time for this app.
Then, upload your provisioning profile to testflight. 
I assume you know the process of getting the profile file from XCode.

This last one is a very IMPORTANT STEP, because all devices added to this profile will automatically notified each time you upload and update a build version on testflight. If they are registered testflight users, you will see their names / emails. If they are not, you will see their UDIDs. But where you will see? Well, when you upload a build, you will see it under Permissions page.

Once you click each of the people and press "Update" (simply update) or "Update and Notify" (update and send email if registered), you will start seeing builds in testflightapp website.

[image]

Comment: can you suggest me the procedure for uploading a build and then which build it is asking to upload?