# iOS TestFlight build notification e-mails repeatedly not being received

Tags: ios, ios8, testflight

We're building an iOS app in iOS 8 using Apple's version of TestFlight (integrated with iTunes Connect, of course). However, the system regularly refuses to send the "new build" notification e-mails to internal testers. In order to get build notification e-mails, I have to remove users from the *internal testers* group and re-invite them. Even when I have done this, the build notification e-mail (although it lists the desired version of the app) doesn't actually trigger an update in my TestFlight iOS app.

Points to note:

- I have the Connect and TestFlight apps installed on my phone.
- This has worked in the past with earlier versions of the app.

I have found other similar questions on Stack Overflow such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698175/unable-to-invite-internal-users-in-apple-testflight) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572098/why-i-cannot-see-new-ios-builds-in-testflight), but none of them seem to deal with the "this happens to me repeatedly" problem. Besides, most of them seem to suggest "remove all internal testers, disable beta testing on the app, then re-add them all" which is not a sustainable solution when we'd like to release multiple new builds per day through our continuous integration system.

Does anyone have any ideas?

ETA: I found [an Apple Developer Forums thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1077672#1077672) on the subject. Not much help but it might be in future.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Comment: Fine by me, I only posted it on SO because there were other related questions on SO and SO is significantly more awesome than Apple Developer Forums :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue, Making changes to the "What to Test" field in the Build page and saving caused notifications to go out instantly for me.

When you upload a new build wait for a bit (I wait an hour) for all the processing to finish, then add the What to Test info and hit save. This seems to work for me quite well.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this is working well for me so far. Perhaps Apple doesn't event want you to leave that field blank. This is definitely a workable solution, thanks!

Comment: Where is the Build page? I don't see "What to Test" anywhere, tnx!

Comment: IIRC, it's a field in one of the tabs in the iTunes Connect portal against the build you have just uploaded.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer works for me. What I want to add is that after I added "What to Test" info, I still couldn't receive notification. Then just uninstall the app and re-install it, all is well.

Comment: For me it worked after I removed all emailid, readded, and saved.

Answer (score 2):

Using Edit, I removed the testers and saved. It says you can't test without testers. I added existing testers to the new build and saved. When I refreshed the page, it said they were notified with the current date.

Comment: This works for me too, removing a tester and adding it again will trigger instant notification